# adf editAll vs. clickToEdit table performance

Tags: performance, oracle-adf

If we have an editable table with two different approaches:
1. Click to edit - Table rendered as read-only initially and user clicks on row to edit.
2. Edit All - Table renders read-only initially and editable on click of an edit button.
Which one will perform better while also providing users with a simple edit feature.

Note that the number of rows is not significant. I am more concerned about the database trips, does edit all generate a lot of trips compared to clickToEdit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click to Edit tables perform better on the client side - this is the recommended approach of the two.
An even more recommended way is a read only table with a pop-up for editing a row.

Comment: Thanks Shay, this makes sense. I have opted for Click-to-Edit.